# Spring: Get Registered URL Pattern in Controller from HttpRequest

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Is there a way to get the registered URL pattern (In Controller) from the incoming HTTP request.

For Example, If my controller code is

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("greeting")
public class Greeting {

    @GetMapping("/{text}")
    public String echo(@PathVariable("text") String text) {
        return text;
    }

}
```

Incoming request is http://localhost:8080/greeting/Hello,
I want to get the mapping value **/greeting/{text}**. Can I achieve the same using any Interceptor or Handler?

I have registered all the original mapping URLs like **/greeting/{text}**, **/users/find/{id}** etc., and want to perform some validation if the incoming request falls into any of those registered requests. I could have achieve the same using one custom method level annotation but I don't want to change all the codes now. It would be nice if I can achieve the same from a single Interceptor or extending any spring handlers.

The above snippet is a sample one. I have 4 to 5 spring applications with different apis and want create a common security package which can achieve the same.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need that? `/greeting/Hello` not enough?

Comment: I have one requirement where I have registered all the controllers URLs like  **/greeting/{text}** in the database and I want to perform some validation, if the incoming request matches the same. I can do it in each method level, but It would be better if can have the logic in one place so that I can reuse it across projects.

Answer (score 4):

You can access this from

```
final String pattern = request.getAttribute(org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE):
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html#BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE

Answer (score 0):

HttpServletRequest request
request.getCurrentUrl() can get the url

Comment: But it won't give me the URL registered in spring Controller (**/greeting/{text}**)